# Wordpress - Count all posts that have a future date to the current one

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for there to count all the posts that are there in future date to the current one

Query:

```
<?php
    $mostra_data_corrente = date('d-m-Y');
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => get_option('customer_postquery'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'metakey_AMC_data',
        )
    ),
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => $mostra_data_corrente,
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $queried_object,
        ) 
    ) ) ) ;
    $conta_risultati = $query->found_posts;
    echo $conta_risultati;
?>
```

Where:

`get_option('customer_postquery')`: dynamically retrieves all the custom post types that have been created

`metakey_AMC_data`: is the meta key where the date of the event (post) is enclosed within the meta_value

`$queried_object`: dynamically retrieves the taxonomy of posts based on the page we are on, thus filtering the posts based on their taxonomy

So my intent is to count all the posts that are there that have a future date to the current one

"It does not count perfectly how many posts exist at a future date compared to the current one"

edit code:

```
<?php
$mostra_data_corrente = date('d-m-Y');
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => get_option('customer_postquery'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'metakey_AMC_data',
            'compare'   => '>',
        )
    ),
    'date_query'     => array(
        'after' => $mostra_data_corrente,
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $queried_object,
        )
    )
) ) ;
$conta_risultati = $query->found_posts;
echo $conta_risultati;
```

result:3 , but it's not the truth because i have 7 result after current date for this taxonomy

Comment: And, what is the actual, specific _problem_? You need to explain what is wrong with what you have tried.

Comment: @04FS I think it was obvious to understand from the moment that I posted the question, that it doesn't count perfectly how many posts exist at a future date compared to the current one

Comment: I think you can try with before and after method in date_query

Comment: @Jinesh i try this before today and after today but not work :(

Comment: can you echo this thing get_option('customer_postquery');?

Comment: @Jinesh if i write: echo get_option('customer_postquery');
i have result 0

Comment: It means post type not saving data in wp_option table can you pass post_type=>'your post type name'

Comment: Find the value of this customer_postquery  in wp_option table

Comment: @Jinesh i have same 0, i don t think the post_type it s a problem, probably my query it s not write good for calculate the post after the current date

Comment: Can you write hard code post type to check the result?

Comment: @Jinesh hard code? excuse me i don t understand

Comment: like this way 'post_type' => 'NAMECPT_ONE'

Comment: @Jinesh if I write it individually before a custom post type and then the other I always get 3, if I write it inside the array I always get 3 if I write it with get option I always get 3, look at my question that I modified it

Comment: what about this $queried_object is it array?

Comment: @Jinesh $queried_object: dynamically retrieves the taxonomy of posts based on the page we are on, thus filtering the posts based on their taxonomy

Comment: so can you print_r($queried_object) and check you are getting proper result or not?

Comment: @Jinesh WP_Term Object ( [term_id] => 7 [name] => Aperitivi [slug] => aperitivi [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 7 [taxonomy] => categoria [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 13 [filter] => raw )

Comment: I think issue in post_type

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to query them like :

```
$currentPostDate = 'get your post date here';
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'the_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'the_date',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
);

$your_custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
$postcount = count($your_custom_query);
```

Think to make it as function in your functions.php file.